# Labmda. Конструкция python

Tags: python, lambda

```
arr = [0, 2, 3, 4, -6, -7, -10]

def count_positives_sum_negatives(arr):
    count_pos = 0
    count_neg = 0
    lambda for x in arr: count_pos + 1 if x >= 0 else count_neg + (-1*(x))
    return [count_pos, count_neg*-1]
```

Выход

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/default/tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from solution import count_positives_sum_negatives
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 4
    lambda (for x in arr): count_pos + 1 if x >= 0 else count_neg + (-1*(x))
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Что делаю не так?

Мне необходимо посчитать количество положительных элементов и сумму отрицательных элементов.
Я решил сделать это через итерацию внутри lambda. Перебирая элементы и добавляю нужные значения в переменные.
Количество элементов не определено.

Comment: После слова lambda должны идти названия аргументов через запятую, а у вас там какой-то непонятный for стоит, вот питон тоже этого не понимает

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил. Не понимаю синтаксис пока.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Пишем "нормальный вариант":

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(arr):
    positive_count = 0
    negative_sum = 0
    for x in arr:
        if x<0:
            negative_sum += x
        elif x>0:
            positive_count += 1
    return [negative_sum, positive_count]
```

2. Понимаем, что в лямбду если и получиться переписать, то выглядеть это будет *очень-неочень*.
3. Но если на производительность можно *забить*:

```
negative_sum  = sum(filter(lambda x: x<0, arr))
positive_count = len(list(filter(lambda x: x>0, arr)))
```

Или так:

```
negative_sum = sum(x for x in arr if x<0)
positive_count = len([x for x in arr if x>0])
```

UPD:
Лямба

```
n, p = (lambda: [sum(x for x in arr if x<0), len([x for x in arr if x>0])])()
```

Comment: Благодарю. А почему вы сказали про производительность? Lambda более затратна? Мне вот показалось, что это будет лаконичным решением.
Через цикл я и сам могу написать, хотелось более емко.

Comment: @Antony сама по себе лямбда ничем в общем-то не отличается от обычных функций. Но в приведенных примерах вы дважды бежите по вашему циклу, это сказывается на производительности. в полноценную лямбду можно записать, добавил (забыл почему-то раньше), но по сути - это просто *склейка* двух строк в одну, а не полноценная лямбда.

Comment: `len([x for x in arr if x>0])` -> `sum(1 for x in arr if x>0)`. Строить список, чтобы измерить его длину, странно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [0, 2, 3, 4, -6, -7, -10]

c, s = 0, 0
for i in arr:
    if i < 0:
        s += i
    else:
        c += 1
print([s, c])

dct = {"s": 0, "c": 0}
[dct.update({"s": dct["s"] + x}) if x < 0 else dct.update({"c": dct["c"] + 1}) for x in arr]
print([dct["s"], dct["c"]])
```